# How can I provide an JSON fragment as an value to SqlParameter in CosmosDB

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

In Cosmos DB I can use Json fragments as part of a where clause for a query such that

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.path.to.propery={"where":{"value":{"is":true}}}
```

yields results (of course if there are any)

now I want to use the same idea when querying using `SqlParamter`s

```
var stmt = new SqlQuerySpec
{
  QueryText = "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.path.to.propery=@myjson",
  Parameters = new SqlParameterCollection()
  {
     new SqlParameter{ Name = "@myjson", Value = ??? } 
  }
};
```

Any idea what (if any at all) needs to go instead of the `???` to have the json fragment `{"where":{"value":{"is":true}}}` in the query

### Edit

Simply adding a `string` as a param value will not work as strings correctly will be enclosed in `"` to prevent SQL injection attacks.

using an anonymous object like

```
myjson = new { where = new { value = new { @is = true } } }
```

might work (I havent tried it out) but wont work in my specif case as the JSON and its structure are unknown at compile time.

Comment: I know nothing about CosmosDB, but the first obvious things to try would be `Value = @"{""where"":{""value"":{""is"":true}}}"` (i.e. just put the JSON in there) and `Value = new { where = new { value = new { @is = true } } }` (i.e. see if it will construct JSON by reflecting over objects). If they were particularly cool kids they might have even considered supporting tuples: `Value = ("where", ("value", ("is", true)))`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert hey thanks for your comment - it helped me finding the solution thou both of your suggestions didnt work out. I clarified my question

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in the form of cosmos DBs `StringToObject` function so that

```
var myjson =  @"{""where"":{""value"":{""is"":true}}}"
var stmt = new SqlQuerySpec
{
    QueryText = "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.path.to.propery=StringToObject(@myjson)",
    Parameters = new SqlParameterCollection()
    {
        new SqlParameter{ Name = "@myjson", Value = myjson } 
    }
};
```